# how can I paging api with WSClient

Tags: java, playframework, completable-future

I have this function to generate users list from api, I had a lot of issues when I tried to paging between users pages.

```
private  CompletionStage<User[]> handelUserResult(WSResponse response) {
    User[]  pageUsers = Json.fromJson(response.asJson().get("values"),User[].class);
    if(response.asJson().get("next") == null){
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(pageUsers);
    }else{
          String nextPageUrl = response.asJson().get("next").asText();
          //get next coming pages

    }
}
```

How can I use `handelUserResult` to return all users from all the pages?